# Sonar and the use of @CheckForNull

Tags: java, sonarqube

I've started to annotate methods with @CheckForNull when those methods are allowed to return null. However Sonar is now complaining about possible NullPointers even though the return value was checked.

```
  @CheckForNull
public Object canReturnNull(){
    return null;
}

public Object canAlsoReturnNull(){
    return null;
}

public void testMethod(){
    if(canReturnNull()!=null){
        Class cls = canReturnNull().getClass(); //Sonar complains about possible NP
    }
    if(canAlsoReturnNull()!=null){
        Class cls = canAlsoReturnNull().getClass(); //Sonar does not complain about possible NP
    }
}

public void testMethod2(){
    Object o = canReturnNull();
    if(o !=null){
        Class cls = o.getClass(); //Sonar does not complain anymore
    }
    if(canAlsoReturnNull()!=null){
        Class cls = canAlsoReturnNull().getClass(); //Sonar does not complain about possible NP
    }
}
```

I know in theory it is possible that the first call to canReturnNull() can return a non-null object and the second one doesn't but is there a way to tell Sonar to treat all subsequent calls to that method in that particular method as checked?

Otherwise I will have to rewrite a lot of code to assign a local variable as in testMethod2 (I know probably best practice anyway but I have a lot of legacy code to deal with.